# Getting LawnChair JSON Obj after storing

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, lawnchair

I'm a little confused on how to retrieve my JSON object from a different page.

Page 1 Snippet [Storing]:

```
$.getJSON(serviceURL + 'getTaskDetails.php?id='+id, storeTasks); //[JSON Format of getTaskDetails][1]

function storeTasks(data) {

  var tasks = Lawnchair({name:'tasks'},function(e){});

  var taskList = data.tasks; //tasks is JSON array name

  tasks.save({key:"task",value:taskList});

  tasks.get("task",function(obj){
    console.info(obj);
  });
}
```

The `.get` returns my object (output from Firebug):

```
key "task"

value   Object { name="Level fireplace mantle", start_date="2012-01-22 00:00:00", created_by="rachel.rinaldi@gmail.com"}
```

How do I reference this from another page?

```
Lawnchair(function(){
        this.get('task', function(obj) {
        console.info(obj);
        })
})
```

The above returns the object, but won't let me reference individual elements (ex: I've tried `obj.name` or `obj.tasks.name` or `obj.Object.name` all result in "undefined")  Any suggestions on what I'm doing wrong?  Maybe I'm storing it incorrectly to begin with?

Comment: I note that you're using different patterns of using the Lawnchair object when setting versus getting.  I've adjusted your code slightly in my answer to use a consistent pattern.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're very close!   Here's your brief answer:  `console.log(obj['value']);`

For those watching from home:

Page one:

```
Lawnchair(function(){
    this.save({key:"task",value:taskList});
});
```

Page two:

```
Lawnchair(function(){
    this.get('task', function(obj) {
        if(obj) {
            console.log("found task");
            console.log(obj['value']);
        } else {
            console.log("task not found");
        }
    })
});
```